# Use values of checkbox based on which is checked, in variable

Tags: javascript, html

I would like to make a variable which has the values of 1 or multiple checkboxes, based on which one is selected. This is what I came up with for now:

```js
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("value1");
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("value2");
var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("value3");

var showvalue = document.getElementById("show-value");


document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
  .forEach(box => box.addEventListener('change', showValue));

function showValue() {
 if (checkbox1.checked === true) {
   showvalue.value = checkbox1.value;
  }
 }
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="checkbox" value="3 maanden"><label for="value1">Value 1</label>
<input id="value2" type="checkbox" value="6 maanden"><label for="value2">Value 2</label>
<input id="value3" type="checkbox" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="value3">Value 3</label>

<input id="show-value" type="hidden"/>
```

But I don't know how to iterate through checkboxes and if the specific one is checked, add it to variable `showvalue`. So what I want for `showvalue` is something like this (based on which checkbox is checked):

```
var showvalue = checkbox1.value + ", " + checkbox2.value + ", " + checkbox3.value;
```

How do I iterate through checkboxes and then if checked = true add that value to `showvalue`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can try this:

```js
var showvalue = document.getElementById("show-value");

var checkboxes = document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]');
checkboxes.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('change', showValue));

function showValue() {
  showvalue.value = Array.from(checkboxes).map(e => e.checked ? e.value : null).filter(Boolean).join(", ");
}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="checkbox" value="3 maanden"><label for="value1">Value 1</label>
<input id="value2" type="checkbox" value="6 maanden"><label for="value2">Value 2</label>
<input id="value3" type="checkbox" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="value3">Value 3</label>

<input id="show-value" type="text"/>
```

Comment: This looks like the cleanest, simplest way, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

For showing I delete the hidden from the showvalue-inputfield and set it to readonly.

For calculating the result I go with foreach through the checkboxes and add if checked to the resultstring the value. The separator `,`   is only set if there is already a partresult. After this at the end just update the value from showvalue.

```js
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("value1");
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("value2");
var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("value3");

var showvalue = document.getElementById("show-value");


document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
  .forEach(box => box.addEventListener('change', showValue));

function showValue() {
    let value = '';
    document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]').forEach(box => {
        if (box.checked === true) {
            if (value.length) value += ', ';
            value += box.value;
        }
    });
    showvalue.value = value;
 }
```

```css
.readonly { background: yellow;}
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="checkbox" value="3 maanden"><label for="value1">Value 1</label>
<input id="value2" type="checkbox" value="6 maanden"><label for="value2">Value 2</label>
<input id="value3" type="checkbox" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="value3">Value 3</label>

<input id="show-value" size=40 class="readonly" readonly/>
```

Comment: I feel like this is the most understandable way and to use in the future for more. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

```
document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
.forEach(box => box.addEventListener('input', showValue));
function showValue(event) {
    var input = event.target;
    var showvalue = document.getElementById('show-value');
    showvalue.value += input.value;
  // tern if statment
    input.checked ? showvalue.type = 'text' : showvalue.type = 'hidden';
  // you can used the original if statment
    if (input.checked) {
      showvalue.type = 'text';
    } else {
      showvalue.type = 'hidden';
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it that what you were looking for?

```js
var checkbox1 = document.getElementById("value1");
var checkbox2 = document.getElementById("value2");
var checkbox3 = document.getElementById("value3");


document.querySelectorAll('input[type=checkbox]')
  .forEach(box => box.addEventListener('change', showValue));

function showValue() {
 if (checkbox1.checked === true) {
   var box1 = checkbox1.value;
  }else{
   var box1 = '';
  }
 if (checkbox2.checked === true) {
   var box2 = checkbox2.value;
  }else{
   var box2 = '';
  }
 if (checkbox3.checked === true) {
   var box3 = checkbox3.value;
  }else{
   var box3 = '';
  }
 document.getElementById("show").value = box1 + ';' + box2 + ';' + box3;
 }
```

```html
<input id="value1" type="checkbox" value="3 maanden"><label for="value1">Value 1</label>
<input id="value2" type="checkbox" value="6 maanden"><label for="value2">Value 2</label>
<input id="value3" type="checkbox" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="value3">Value 3</label>

<input id="show" class="readonly" readonly/>
```

Answer (score 0):

Just use querySelector and use name attribute to check for what is checked or not. An example:

```js
let result = [];

const setup = () => {
    
    const entry1 = document.querySelectorAll('[name="entry1"]');
  entry1.forEach(input => input.addEventListener('change', onChange));

}

const onChange = () => {
    const checkedEntry1 = document.querySelectorAll('[name="entry1"]:checked');
  result = [];
  checkedEntry1.forEach(input => result.push(input.value));
  document.querySelector('#show-value').value = result.join(', ');
}

//load
window.addEventListener('load', setup);
```

```html
<input id="value1" name="entry1" type="checkbox" value="3 maanden"><label for="value1">Value 1</label>
<input id="value2" name="entry1" type="checkbox" value="6 maanden"><label for="value2">Value 2</label>
<input id="value3" name="entry1" type="checkbox" value="Uitgeschreven"><label for="value3">Value 3</label>

<input id="show-value" type="hidden">
```